# Flutter modules in Xamarin project?

Tags: flutter, xamarin, flutter-module

I have a Xamarin application that I want to use as a simple portal to other applications. I wanted to know if it was possible to integrate flutter modules into it.

The Flutter documentation (https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app) only seems to talk about Java and Kotlin, and there's no graddle files in xamarin apps.. As for Xamarin, I tried to follow the procedure to bind an AAR file (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar) but I can't find my object classes in the reference explorer...

Comment: You can check this link about [Flutter for Xamarin.Forms developers](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/flutter-for/xamarin-forms-devs). This is the document about how to use the flutter in xamarin.forms.

Comment: Thanks for your response but unfortunately this documentation does not explain how to work with Flutter modules in Xamarin. It only presents the framework, comparing Dart code to C# code for Xamarin developers.

Comment: You can check this GitHub about [Flutnet Xamarin Bindings](https://github.com/flutnet/flutnet-xamarin-bindings#flutnet-xamarin-bindings) and they provide the Nuget package [Flutnet.Interop.Android](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flutnet.Interop.Android/).